# how to fire all validation controls from client side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation-controls

In an aspx page I have different validation controls (some required and some custom). Please guide me how to fire all validation controls of page in client side code.

I am aware  ValidatorEnable() which accept id of control and enable it. But I want to fire/ exeute all of them using client side code.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have validation groups, use:

```
function myFunction(grop)
 {
  if (Page_ClientValidate(grop))
     {

        /*do stuff here*/

        }
}
```

and Page_ClientValidate() without groups )